# How to convert nested sql into Codeigniter Active record

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

How do I write query statement in CodeIgniter active record?

Here is View code in **menu.php** file with php procedure. (this code can run)

```
    <?php

    $m=1;

    echo "<table>
    <tr>
      <td>No</td><td>Menu</td><td>Submenu 1</td><td>Submenu 2</td><td>Submenu 3</td>
    </tr>";

        // main menu
        $query1 = $this->db->query("select id,title,parent,order from tbl_menu where parent='0' order by order;");
        foreach($query1->result_array() as $r) {

    echo "<tr>
        <td>$m</td><td>$row[title]</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td>
    </tr>";

        $m++;
        $s1=1;

        // submenu 1
        $query2 = $this->db->query("select * from tbl_menu where parent='$row[id]' order by order;");
        foreach($query2->result_array() as $r) {

    echo "<tr>
        <td></td><td >$s1</td><td>$r[title]</td><td>-</td><td>-</td>
    </tr>";

            $s1++;
            $s2=1;

            // submenu 2

            $query3 = $this->db->query("select * from tbl_menu where parent='$r[id]' order by order;");
            foreach($query3->result_array() as $r2) {


    echo "<tr>
        <td></td><td></td><td >$s2</td><td>$r2[title]</td><td>-</td>
    </tr>";

                $s2++;
                $s3=1;
                // submenu 3
                $query4 = $this->db->query("select * from tbl_menu where parent='$r2[id]' order by order;");
                foreach($query4->result_array() as $r3) {

    echo "<tr>
        <td></td><td></td><td></td><td>$s3</td><td>$r3[title]</td>
    </tr>";
        $s3++;

                } // submenu 3
            } // submenu 2
        } // submenu 1
    } // main menu

    echo"</table>";


    ?>
```

I changed into this... (this is error)

```
    <?php

    $m=1;

    echo "<table>
    <tr>
      <td>No</td><td>Menu</td><td>Submenu 1</td><td>Submenu 2</td><td>Submenu 3</td>
    </tr>";

        // main menu
        foreach($query1 as $r) {

    echo "<tr>
        <td>$m</td><td>$row[title]</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td>
    </tr>";

        $m++;
        $s1=1;

        // submenu 1
        foreach($query2 as $r) {

    echo "<tr>
        <td></td><td >$s1</td><td>$r[title]</td><td>-</td><td>-</td>
    </tr>";

            $s1++;
            $s2=1;

            // submenu 2

            foreach($query3 as $r2) {


    echo "<tr>
        <td></td><td></td><td >$s2</td><td>$r2[title]</td><td>-</td>
    </tr>";

                $s2++;
                $s3=1;
                // submenu 3
                foreach($query4 as $r3) {

    echo "<tr>
        <td></td><td></td><td></td><td>$s3</td><td>$r3[title]</td>
    </tr>";
        $s3++;

                } // submenu 3
            } // submenu 2
        } // submenu 1
    } // main menu

    echo"</table>";


    ?>
```

Here is Model code in **Menu_model.php** file.

```
<?php


class Menu_model extends CI_Model {

    public function menu_q1() {
    $this->db->select('*')->from('tbl_menu')->where('parent','0')->order_by('order', 'ASC');
    $query1 = $this->db->get();
    return $query1->result_array();
    }

    public function menu_q2() {
    $this->db->select('*')->from('tbl_menu')->where('parent',$row['id'])->order_by('order', 'ASC');
    $query2 = $this->db->get();
    return $query2->result_array();
    }

    public function menu_q3() {
    $this->db->select('*')->from('tbl_menu')->where('parent',$r['id'])->order_by('order', 'ASC');
    $query3 = $this->db->get();
    return $query3->result_array();
    }

    public function menu_q4() {
    $this->db->select('*')->from('tbl_menu')->where('parent',$r2['id'])->order_by('order', 'ASC');
    $query4 = $this->db->get();
    return $query4->result_array();
    }

}

?>
```

Here is Controller code in **Menu_controller.php** file.

```
<?php

Class Menu_controller extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('menu_model'); //Load profil_model
    }

    public function profil() {

        $query1 = $this->profil_model->menu_q1();
        $query2 = $this->profil_model->menu_q2();
        $query3 = $this->profil_model->menu_q3();
        $query4 = $this->profil_model->menu_q4();

    $this->load->view('profil', array('query1' => $query1,'query2' => $query2,'query3' => $query3,'query4' => $query4));


}

?>
```

This is the table

```
    --------------------------------------------------------
    No  |  Menu       | Submenu 1 | Submenu 2  | Submenu 3
    --------------------------------------------------------
    $m  | $row[title] | -         | -          | -
        |          $s1| $r[title] | -          | -
        |             |        $s2| $r2[title] | -
        |             |           |         $s3| $r3[title]
    --------------------------------------------------------
```

But getting error in this statement:

1) where('parent',$row['id'])

2) where('parent',$r['id'])

3) where('parent',$r2['id'])

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Snippets only have value for HTML/JS/Javascript, so I changed it them to code snippets. I also removed the hint to mark code as html, because it actually is php.

Answer (score 0):

That error is occurring because you are not passing the data into model function. You cannot use any data without pass value to function.

```
public function menu_q2($row) {
    $this->db->select('*')->from('tbl_menu')->where('parent',$row['id'])->order_by('order', 'ASC');
    $query2 = $this->db->get();
    return $query2->result_array();
    }

    public function menu_q3($r) {
    $this->db->select('*')->from('tbl_menu')->where('parent',$r['id'])->order_by('order', 'ASC');
    $query3 = $this->db->get();
    return $query3->result_array();
    }

    public function menu_q4($r2) {
    $this->db->select('*')->from('tbl_menu')->where('parent',$r2['id'])->order_by('order', 'ASC');
    $query4 = $this->db->get();
    return $query4->result_array();
    }
```

If you pass the value in function (example code above), then you can use that in respectively function.